# Strange side effect of remarking Write-Host

Tags: powershell

I am seeing some rather odd behavior I can't seem to explain.

This code to stream a text file works as shown just fine.

```
$journalPath = "$(Split-Path $($script:myInvocation.myCommand.path) -parent)\Journals"

$journals = Get-ChildItem $journalPath -filter "journal.*.txt"

Write-Host "Streaming"
foreach ($journal in $journals) {
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("$journalPath\$journal")
    do {
        $line = ($reader.ReadLine()).Trim()
        if (-not ($line.StartsWith("'"))) {
            Write-Host $line
        }
    } until ($line -eq $null)

    $reader.Close()
}
```

However, if I rem out the Write-Host line I get

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

on line 9, the `$reader.ReadLine()` line. Why on earth would a simple Write-Line have this impact?

Comment: If you "rem" it out? There's no rem directive I PowerShell. Please show us the failing code

Comment: You should get this exception every time. I guess, you just not patient enough to wait your code to finish its job or your file just to long.

Comment: Rem as in remark. So
# Write-Host $line

Comment: PetSerAl, you are on the spot, in that I saw the error, killed execution and took the error at face value. I just let it run without the remarked Write-Host and indeed it barfs. My first thought was I need a Do While not a Do Until, but that is also failing. So, with a streaming approach, is there an elegant way to implement Do Until EOF, or is a Try Catch or Break the only real way to handle it? Those are kinda ugly. ;)

Comment: `while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) { $line = $line.Trim(); ... }`

Comment: `while ( -not $reader.EndOfStream ) { # loop body here }`

Comment: JosefZ, that is so obvious I just face palmed. Thanks for that! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike (so-called *pretest*) `While () {…}` loop, all (so-called *posttest*) `Do {…} While ()` as well as `Do {…} Until ()` loops will always perform their code block *at least once*, because the condition occurs at the end of the loop.

Next example shows basic scenarios of looping a file content line-by-line including **inept** ones showing if read line might evaluate to a null-valued expression in current iteration/repetition. Note that you need not to call up [.NET File Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) `[System.IO.File]`.

```
$journalPath = "$(Split-Path $($script:myInvocation.myCommand.Path) -parent)\Journals"
$journals = Get-ChildItem $journalPath -filter "journal*.txt"
foreach ($journal in $journals) {
    Write-Host "`r`n" (" " * 10) "testing " $journal.Name

    'DO {} WHILE ( $line -ne $null )'
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("$journalPath\$journal")
    Do {
         $line = $reader.ReadLine()
         Write-Host (" " * 14) ($line -eq $null) $reader.EndOfStream
       } While ( $line -ne $null )
    $reader.Close()

    'DO {} UNTIL ( $line -eq $null )'
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("$journalPath\$journal")
    Do { 
         $line = $reader.ReadLine()
         Write-Host (" " * 14) ($line -eq $null) $reader.EndOfStream
       } Until ( $line -eq $Null )
    $reader.Close()

    'DO {} WHILE ( -not $reader.EndOfStream )'
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("$journalPath\$journal")
    Do {
         $line = $reader.ReadLine()
         Write-Host (" " * 14) ($line -eq $null) $reader.EndOfStream
       } While ( -not $reader.EndOfStream )
    $reader.Close()

    'DO {} UNTIL ( $reader.EndOfStream )'
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("$journalPath\$journal")
    Do { 
         $line = $reader.ReadLine()
         Write-Host (" " * 14) ($line -eq $null) $reader.EndOfStream
       } Until ( $reader.EndOfStream )
    $reader.Close()

    'WHILE ( -not $reader.EndOfStream ) {}' 
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("$journalPath\$journal")
    While ( -not $reader.EndOfStream) {
         $line = $reader.ReadLine()
         Write-Host (" " * 14) ($line -eq $null) $reader.EndOfStream
    }
    $reader.Close()

    'FOREACH-OBJECT {}'
    $journal | Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host (" " * 14) ($_ -eq $null)
    }
}
```

Anyone can see that the only acceptable scenarios are those with `'FOREACH-OBJECT {}'` and `'WHILE ( -not $reader.EndOfStream ) {}'` subheaders:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\37898929.ps1

            testing  journal37898929-none_lines.txt
DO {} WHILE ( $line -ne $null )
               True True
DO {} UNTIL ( $line -eq $null )
               True True
DO {} WHILE ( -not $reader.EndOfStream )
               True True
DO {} UNTIL ( $reader.EndOfStream )
               True True
WHILE ( -not $reader.EndOfStream ) {}
FOREACH-OBJECT {}

            testing  journal37898929-some_lines.txt
DO {} WHILE ( $line -ne $null )
               False False
               False False
               False True
               True True
DO {} UNTIL ( $line -eq $null )
               False False
               False False
               False True
               True True
DO {} WHILE ( -not $reader.EndOfStream )
               False False
               False False
               False True
DO {} UNTIL ( $reader.EndOfStream )
               False False
               False False
               False True
WHILE ( -not $reader.EndOfStream ) {}
               False False
               False False
               False True
FOREACH-OBJECT {}
               False
               False
               False

PS D:\PShell>
```

Further reading: [**PowerShell loops**: For, Foreach, While, Do-Until, Continue, Break](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-loops-for-foreach-while-do-until-continue-break/)